# What function can turn $z=x+iy$ into something involving $xy$?

Tags: complex-analysis

What function can turn $z=x+iy$ into something involving $xy$?

What function takes the real parts of $z$ and then multiplies them?

Or would I perhaps need to consider the point $(x,iy)$, rather than the expression $x+iy$?

Comment: $f(z) = \text{Re}(z)\text{Im}(z)$?

Comment: Certainly $\frac12z^2$ "involves" $xy$ as its imaginary part.

Answer (score 0):

$$
z\mapsto{z^2-(\bar z)^2\over4i}
$$